# Creating new columns in dataframe conditional on the sum of another column value in R

Tags: r, sum, conditional-statements, bar-chart

I'm fairly new to R and I have not quite been able to find a solution to my problem yet online.  I have a database (brought in as a csv). the head looks like this:

[image: data head]

The variables I'm interested in are sex (which is either M or F) and seropostive (either O or 1). What I would like to do is make a grouped bar graph where, for example, I can display the sum of the number of seropostive/seronegative female bats vs the sums of the total seropostitive/seronegative male bats.  The part that has me stuck is getting the sums and plotting them.  I tried to create new variables to represent the sums thinking I could just plot them:

```
data2$fp <- sum(data2$seropositive == 1 & data2$sex == "F") 
data2$fn <- sum(data2$seropositive == 0 & data2$sex == "F")
data2$mp <- sum(data2$seropositive == 1 & data2$sex == "M")
data2$mn <- sum(data2$seropositive == 0 & data2$sex == "M")
```

But this gives me a new variable where the row value is the same for each observation- the respective sum:
[image]

To reproduce data

```
dput(head(data2, 20))
structure(data2)
str(data2)
```

[image: Output from str(data2)]

I've been going through a lot of stack posts and can't seem to find a solution to this- can anybody give a suggestion as to how I could and what I've done wrong? Thanks!

I'm editing because I was able to get part of what I want using this code:

```
ggplot(data2, aes(x=sex, y=seropositive)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

The only thing I want to add is now show 2 bars for each sex- one for seropositive=1, the other seropositive=0.  Right now it's plotting the sum of seropositve=1.

[image]

Comment: Please use `dput` to show a small reproudicble example

Comment: My data is in a csv file- can I used `dput` with a csv file?  I don't see an answer to this online.  Thanks!

Comment: That code worked in my R script console, does it work in my post now?  Thanks again!

Comment: I added the edit- sorry if that's not what you mean, I'm struggling to find any reference of example of the code/function you mean.  Thanks again!

Comment: @jrokh Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the problem is that you are creating new columns not new variables. The 4 columns at the end of `data2` are those respective values. Remove `data2$` from your code to sum the counts to create new variables.

To plot, there are two ways. You can plot using a bar chart or other plots by plotting

`plot(data2[1, 13:16])`

(which takes the first 4 values of the new columns you created, or if you changed the code to actually declare new variables, you can plot those values if you put them in a `data.frame` or vector.

Comment: When I try your way (example code after), and try to make the plot I get an error saying undefined columns selected  `fp <- sum(data2$seropositive == 1 & data2$sex == "F") plot(data2[1, 13:16])`

Comment: @jrokh can you send the `str()` of the table?

Comment: I added those lines of code to the question- please let me know if I did it wrong, I'm pretty new and having a hard time finding a good reference.  Thanks for the patience!

Comment: Can you share the output of str(data2) when you run the line? Thanks!

Comment: I pasted it, sorry about that.

Comment: The way I was showing with `plot(data2[1, 13:16])` works for your previous code where you run `data2$fp <- sum(data2$seropositive == 1 & data2$sex == "F") 
data2$fn <- sum(data2$seropositive == 0 & data2$sex == "F")
data2$mp <- sum(data2$seropositive == 1 & data2$sex == "M")
data2$mn <- sum(data2$seropositive == 0 & data2$sex == "M")`. Then you can plot using ggplot like below.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked and an R fluent friend as showed me this solution with ggplot   `ggplot(data2, aes(x=sex, fill=as.character(seropositive))) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge") +
  xlab("Sex")+
  ylab("Count") +
  ggtitle("Seropositivity by Sex") +
  geom_text(stat='count', aes(label=..count..), ) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  labs(fill= "Seropositive") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name= "Seropositive", labels=
                        c("0=Negative", "1= Positive")) `

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is something like this (with many more columns) :

```
set.seed(123)
data2 <- data.frame(sex = sample(c('M', 'F'), 20, replace = TRUE), 
                    seropositive = sample(c(1, 0), 20, replace = TRUE))
```

You could do :

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data2 %>%
  count(sex, seropositive = factor(seropositive)) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(sex, n, fill = seropositive) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')
```

[image]